# Using your own version of Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, build, json.net, .net-assembly, strongname

I've extended Newtonsoft.Json with some new functionality for JsonSchema.

The problem is that I cannot include the Newtonsoft.Json assembly to my project.

When I do, everything compiles, but at runtime it crashes once it try to load System.Net.Http.Formatting. Since this assembly uses 4.5.0.0 of Newtonsoft.Json it triggers the redirect, but the redirect only works with signed assemblies and I don't have the signing key for Newtonsoft.Json.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/work/visualstudio/x/x/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\work\visualstudio\x\x\bin
Calling assembly : System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\work\visualstudio\x\x\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\x\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.5.0.0 redirected to 6.0.0.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

I've tried signing with the "dynamic" key inside Newtonsoft.Json, but that's different than the one they sign with and I just get another error that they are not the same.

Anyone have a solution to this, or another trick on how to use this assembly without renaming everything.

Comment: I've added a feature request for Microsoft to enable multiple publikkeytoken's with redirect. That would solve a lot of issues. Not sure how easy it would be to fix though.

Comment: Here's the report for Microsoft:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/932677/missing-multiple-publikkeytoken-support-for-assemblyindentity-and-bindingredirect